# ADF - The data type SqlBigDecimal is not supported when writing from Money to Decimal column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, bigdecimal

I have a copy data activity in Azure Data Factory that takes the output of a stored procedure and then writes to CSV file. I have a Money columns (Precision: 19 Scale: 4) in the source that are converted into Decimal columns in the CSV Sink. I'm getting an error that SqlBigDecimal is not supported but the mapping looks good and it should convert the data to Decimal from Money not BigDecimal.

I used to have the same problem but with writing to Parquet file. This issue got resolved by itself somehow. I don't know what I did exactly to resolve that.

"Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The data type SqlBigDecimal is not supported.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'"

Comment: I think maybe we can use String type by default, so we dont need to import the schema.

Comment: I fixed it by adding new procedure with Varchar as output. I don't know why in one pipeline it worked and in the other didn't

Comment: Do you mean it works when using Varchar but not when using Money?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple test to sink money type column into a csv.

1. First, I created a table in Azure SQL

```sql
create table dbo.test(
id int,
salary money
);

insert into dbo.test values (1,3500.1234);

insert into dbo.test values (2,3465.1234);
```

2. Query the rows via stored procudure in the Copy Activity. I didnt set any mapping and import schema.
   [image]
3. Then sink to an empty csv file.
   [image]
   It will create the csv file.
   [image]
4. After I run debug, we can see the result:
   [image]